# pattern matching in a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, loops

i have a list :

```
l= [3, 0, 6, 4, 3, 0, 6, 4, 3, 0, 6, 4, 3, 0, 6, 4, 3, 0, 6, 3, 4]
```

now i want to check if while going from index(x) to index(x+1) does it fall in any of the following pattern_list
`pattern=['03','34','46','60']`.
If that exists then make another list k where values are stored in the form 0 or 1, meaning 0 no pattern and 1 pattern exists.
e.g.

```
k=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
```

I tried this :

```
s_1_list=[]
str_1 = ""

for i in l:
    str_1 += str(i)
      
regexList_1= ['03','34','46','60']
for regex in regexList_1:
    s_1 = str_1.count(regex)
    s_1_list.append(s_1)
    print("Number of times " + regex + " repeated= ", s_1)
```

output :

```
Number of times 03 repeated=  0
Number of times 34 repeated=  1
Number of times 46 repeated=  0
Number of times 60 repeated=  0
```

but this doest give me a new list as desired with the following output, can anyone suggest how to proceed ?

Comment: You are using simple fixed strings, not regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over `s1`, checking if any of the patterns are found at that index, and put `0` or `1` in the result list.

```
s_1_list = [1 if str_1[i:i+2] in regexList_1 else 0 for i in range(len(str_1)-1)]
```

Comment: this works , i would request you to edit the answer and add the missing bracket in the range.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

```
pattern = ['03', '34', '46', '60']
l = [3, 0, 6, 4, 3, 0, 6, 4, 3, 0, 6, 4, 3, 0, 6, 4, 3, 0, 6, 3, 4]
k = []

for i in range(len(l) - 1):
    temp = ''
    temp += str(l[i]) + str(l[i + 1])
    if temp in pattern:
        k.append(1)
    else:
        k.append(0)
print(k)
```